# Reading string from CSV and parsing to date

Tags: java, string, parsing, date, csv

I am reading from a csv file and store the string as follows:

```
                date=st.nextToken();
```

The format of the date is `2014-09-17T12:06:00.0000000Z`, so I define:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX");
```

When I try to parse,

```
                current_date=formatter.parse(date);
```

I get an exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Date"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since you get the exception `Unparseable date: "Date"` , are you sure you're not passing in the text "Date" there, e.g. from a header row in the .csv file ? (but note that there can't be 7 digits in a millisecond field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSX");

    System.out.println(formatter.parse("2014-09-17T12:06:00.0000000Z"));
}
```

So I guess the problem is elsewhere. Either you receive data that is not as you expect it to be, or there is a typo somewhere?

Try to print all dates before you parse them, so you know what you actually parse.

Comment: Indeed, when you pass a string written by you it works (I also tried that...). However, when reading it directly from the CSV file it doesn't work any more...

Comment: @mbezunartea Then you debug it. You e.g. add this line to your code right before you try to parse the date: `System.out.println("Trying to parse date '" + your_date_variable + "'");` so you can see exactly the string you are trying to parse. Don't miss those single quotes, they're helpful to discover if the string contains whitespace(not harmful in your particular case though) or unprintable characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Date date = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(str).toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```